# Save a object into Database column in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle11g, blob

I have different objects like following:

Link: icon, url, text

FAQ: text en, text de, desc en, desc de

Category: text, parent

To track all changes on these objects I have created a table in my oracle DB that should store every change made by a different user. 
I have the columns *oldValue*, *newValue* and a *classAffected* column which each should contain the whole object e.g. a Category. *oldValue* should contain the old Values, *newValue* the changes that were made by a specific user and *classAffected* the name of the object that is in the two columns (Category, link, etc.).

How can I save each object (Link, FAQ, Category) into the columns? Is there a way to put them into a blob and save them so that I can read them when I load it to restore the object with all attributes?
I store large strings with a blob in my databases. I use ASP.NET and write my application in C# if this makes any difference.

Comment: Writing **XML Files** would be Helpful I guess!

Comment: @جمشیدکامران unfortunately my boss wants all the data stored in a database

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. You just need to serialize objects.
[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx) you can read more about it.